# extendscript object is invalid

Tags: extendscript

InDesign scripting question.
I know what need to write with var. I just try to understand what happen...
There is my script:

```
function myalert(s){
    var w = new Window('palette')
    ws = w.add('statictext',undefined,s)
    w.show()
    $.sleep(1000)
    w.close()
}

myalert('hello')
alert(ws)
```

alert:
1. [Object StaticText]
2. JavaScript Error! Object is invalid...

Question: why this happen? Why error after alert? ws already deleted from memory? Then why I see alert? Not deleted? Then why I see error?

Answer (score 1):

1. First `myalert()` executes and you see 'hello' alert.
2. Then `myalert()` finishes and `ws` gets deleted along with `w` (which is local to `myalert()`).
3. Then you try accessing `ws` in global scope - after it was deleted - and get the error.

See:

```js
var w  = 100 // global

function myalert(s){
    var w = new Window('palette') // local (shadows 100)
    ws = w.add('statictext',undefined,s) // global
    w.show()
    $.sleep(1000)
    w.close()
    alert('In myalert() w = ' + w)
    alert('In myalert() ws = ' + ws)
}

myalert('hello')
alert('Global, w = ' + w)
alert('Global, ws = ' + ws)
```

If you don't use `var`, both `w` and `ws` will stay in global scope:

```js
function myalert(s){
    w = new Window('palette')
    ws = w.add('statictext',undefined,s)
    w.show()
    $.sleep(1000)
    w.close()
    alert('[myalert] w = ' + w)
    alert('[myalert] ws = ' + ws)
}

myalert('hello')
alert('[global] w = ' + w)
alert('[global] ws = ' + ws)
```

PS. You can also dump objects on console with `$.writeln('ws = ' + ws)`